# Lambda error: Array buffer allocation failed

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have some Lambda with large code. When I try to run tests everything works fine.

After deploying, I try running it in AWS console and see the following error:

```
RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed
at new ArrayBuffer (<anonymous>)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/brotli/build/encode.js:21:207)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/brotli/compress.js:1:14)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/brotli/index.js:1:20)
START RequestId: dc611535-421d-4bb9-9632-1f17f016d093 Version: $LATEST
RequestId: dc611535-421d-4bb9-9632-1f17f016d093 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 7
Runtime.ExitError
END RequestId: dc611535-421d-4bb9-9632-1f17f016d093
REPORT RequestId: dc611535-421d-4bb9-9632-1f17f016d093  Duration: 16226.67 ms   Billed Duration: 16227 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 60 MB
```

I saw similar cases, regarding max Memory size, but in my case used memory less than max memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

128MB of memory, if you process very large files, are very few, and don't forget that in Lambda Functions the CPU allocation is directly proportioned with the allocated memory.
So, try to increase the memory (at least 512MB).

Anyway, I don't know what logic is involved in code, but are you sure that Lambdas are the best solution here?
How much large are the files involved? Is an ETL, a batch processing, or something else?